# Should we mention as nullable: false on t.references fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

Should we mention from, to as nullable: false as well

```
  def change
    create_table :marriages do |t|
      t.references :from
      t.references :to
      t.date :marriage_date, nullable: false
    
      t.timestamps
    end
```

Comment: Firstly it is `null` not `nullable`. I guess your question is whether the `t.references` column can be nil or not then the answer is it depends on your system. If there is no way that a record of marriages table can have empty `from_id` and `to_id` then you should add the constraint `null: false` to ensure the data integrity of your system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to enforce that it can't be `NULL`, then yes.

Also note that it should be `null: false` – not `nullable: false`.